# Locating ShadowDom element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, shadow-dom

I am trying to automate the search box using Selenium. Search box Locator is inside the shadow-dom.

Hence I can not use traditional, `XPath` and `CSS` Locators to send text inside the Search box.

Using JS path I am able to locate the SEARCHBOX.

The issue is in the Js path > `.ui8wc_92` > `#ui8wc_93` and `#ui8wc_98-outer`  > are generated dynamically and keeps changing.

I would really appreciate it, if anyone can share knowledge regarding, how to make this js path unique if they have come across similar issue.

JS PATH FOR SEARCH BOX:

```
WebElement SerachBox = (WebElement) jse.executeScript("return     document.querySelector('body > ui9-area > ui9-static-area-header.ui8wc_92').shadowRoot.querySelector('#ui8wc_93').shadowRoot.querySelector('#ui8wc_98-outer')");`
```

I tried using wild cards but they don't seem to work.

Comment: can you share the url of the website?